# $B(X)$ and $B(X)^{**}$ for superreflexive Banach spaces $X$

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. It is well-known that $A^{**}$ with either Arens product has separately weak$^{*}$ continuous multiplication if and only if $A$ is Arens regular [Theorem 1, [DuncanHuseiniun1979](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0308210500017170)].
Second, the algebra of operators $B(X)$ for a reflexive Banach space $X$ is Arens regular if and only if $X$ is ultrareflexive [Theorem 4.4, [FaalEbrahimi2016](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972715001835)]. If $X$ is [superreflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Super-reflexive_space), then it is ultrareflexive, but the converse is not known to be true or false [Corollary 4.5 in the [same article](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972715001835)].

Thus, let $M = B(X)^{**}$ for a superreflexive $X$. $M$ has an isometric representation $M\to B(F)$ on a superreflexive Banach space $F$ [Theorem 1, [Daws2004](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609303003072)], and a weak$^{*}$ continuous faithful representation $\pi:M\to B(E)$ on a reflexive Banach space $E$ [Corollary 3.8, [Daws2007](https://doi.org/10.4064/sm178-3-3)].

**Question:** Can $B(X)$ for a superreflexive $X$ be Dedekind finite? How about $M = B(X)^{**}$ ?

---

**Edit:** There exist superreflexive hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces [[Ferenczi1997](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02773800)] for which $B(X)$ is Dedekind finite [Corollary 1.7, [Laustsen2003](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0017089502008947)]. Can $B(X)^{**}$ be Dedekind finite for these $X$ ?